# Save path of FileUpload Control after postback

Tags: asp.net

I want save path to file after postback in FileUpload  asp.net controls like:

```
function GetPathToDownloadPictures() {
    var pathToDownLoadPicture = document.getElementById('<%= UploadPicturesNews.ClientID %>').value;
    document.getElementById('<%= PathToPicturesHidden.ClientID %>').value = pathToDownLoadPicture;
}

window.document.onload = AddPathToUploadControl();

function AddPathToUploadControl() {
    var pathToDownLoadPicture = document.getElementById('<%= PathToPicturesHidden.ClientID %>').value;
    document.getElementById('<%= UploadPicturesNews.ClientID %>').value = pathToDownLoadPicture;
}
```

Add path from FileUpload to HiddenField and after postback add Path from HiddenField to FileUpload, but not working....
Help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original file path is not available any more in modern browsers, as this information is regarded a security risk.

Depending on the browser, you either do not receive any path information, or [c:\fakepath](http://devio.wordpress.com/2012/04/02/computer-says-fakepath/) on IE.

Comment: But I can create my own FileUpload Control(Button and Label)?